# Xcode 10 it constantly is crashing with no errors

Tags: ios, xcode10

I installed Xcode 10 but keeps on crashing sometimes it crash the moment is loading a project or playground but is not showing any error it all. Any of you are experience this issue and if you have had how did you fixed?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: I have not seen the issue, and there's many users using Xcode 10 now that it's on production. My guess is that this is something wrong with your installation, your dependencies, or something specific your project.

Comment: I would suggest ruling things out one at a time. Does it work with a brand new project? If so, it's a project issue. If not, try completely removing Xcode. Delete your derived data and reinstall.

Comment: Or try to open the MacOS console and check errors when it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is getting because of Mac OS update 
if you are using GitLab, Please reclone project repository.
After reclone application will working fine.
Clear all derived data and empty trash before opening project.